# About exclamatives with interrogative form

Tags: inversion, exclamatives

> Did I do something stupid last night!

I suppose it can be expressed by: What a stupid thing I did last night!

> Wow! Can she sing!

It means that She is really good at singing.

> Look at those ones!  Aren’t they amazing!

In this case, I feel confused. It means they are so amazing but why a negative form? Can I say "Are they amazing!"?

Answer (score 1):

"Aren't they amazing!" (or "Are they not amazing!")
are rhetorical questions, whose meaning could be expanded like this:
"I think they are amazing! Do you disagree?"

A rhetorical question isn't expecting an answer, but expressing an opinion.
[American Heritage Dictionary "rhetorical question"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=rhetorical%20question)
n. A question to which no answer is expected, often used for rhetorical effect.

The sentence is a question grammatically, but it can be ended with an exclamation point to express the intensity of the expression.

Comment: Right! I've got it. So can I say " Are they amazing!" as a exclamative clause without rhetorical effect ?

Comment: @Jones That form "Are they amazing!", might be used as well. It would probably be less common than "Aren't they amazing!".